# How to add user authentication in generic delete view in django2.0.6

Tags: django, authentication, django-2.0

I have a page which displays posts of all user and user can only delete his posts. 
Heres the code:

```
class PostDelete(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'dashboard/post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:posts')
```

post_delete.html:

```
{% extends 'dashboard/sidebar.html' %}

{% block title %}Confirmation{% endblock %}

{% block mainpage %}
<div id="page-wrapper" align="center">
  <div id="page-inner">
      <h1>New post</h1>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
          Are you sure you want to delete?
          <br>
          <button class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
          <a href="{% url 'dashboard:posts' %}" class="btn btn-primary">No</a>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Urls.py:

```
path('delete/<int:pk>',views.PostDelete.as_view(),name='delete'),
```

How do I add user authentication code? 
If it were a function I would have used " if request.user.is_authenticated "
But I don't know how to achieve this thing in a class. If you need an excerpt of another code then comment. Thanks!

Comment: I assume the user has to be the `.author`? of the `Post`?

Comment: Hey willem, yes that is a foreign key to my users. Thing is I can use urls to access the post_delete page, every post can be deleted and that delete view is accessed by its pk in url. For eg if my post_id is 5 then I can delete it by typing url : posts/delete/5 . Thing is this raises security issue that anyone can delete anything. Can you help what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class PostDelete(UserPassesTestMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'dashboard/post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:posts')
    raise_exception = True

    def test_func(self):
        self.object = self.get_object() 
        return self.object.user == self.request.user
```

Comment: What do I write in place of object?

Comment: @manjy it's result of `self.get_object() ` method. Check update.

Comment: i get redirected to this url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/dashboard/delete/17. Is something wrong

Comment: @manjy It's default behaviour. If you need 403 error instead add `raise_exception = True` to your view.